# How to free a pointer immediately after returning it?

Tags: c++, c, stack

hey this is my first post and this is for a homework assignment for my theoretical data structures class. The question I'm asking isn't really apart of the assignment but would make the code cleaner if it is possible. (If it is of concern the assignment is to make a reverse polish notation calculator using a linked list stack.)

What I want to do is this

```
char* postEval(char* equation)
{
     char* curChar = equation;
     struct stackNode* stack = NULL;

      /*Alot of processing (hint: stack gets initialized during this)*/

      /****Is there a way to free the node after returning it?? --
           this is pseudo-code!*****/
      return FreeThenReturn(stack->data);  
 }
```

I know I could `sprintf()` or `strcpy()` it into a temporary variable so I could free the node then return the temp varaible but, is there a better way??

EDIT: I'm unsure what is unclear but yes I'm trying to return a copy of the 'data' member (which is a char*) back to the calling function. This is problematic because I need to free the memory of the stack and just send a copy of the data stored there. I know it seems weird to do it this way but this how the teacher specifically told us to do so. We cannot edit the struct stackNode definition nor the prototype of postEval() at all. struct stackNode definition is as follows:

```
    struct stackNode
    {
          char* data;
          struct stackNode *next;
    }
```

Furthermore, the function postEval() is basically just a loop with a switch statement which parses each char of the variable 'equation' and solves the equation then returns the answer as a char*. Our teacher merely wants to see if we can solve it using stacks...that's the point. I know it'd be easier not doing it this way but meh I didn't make the assignment.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking for! Either semantically (why would you want to do that), and as well for the insufficient code example (provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: You discuss `sprintf` and `strcpy` which hints at a lack of understanding of what a pointer is. You sure you've thought this through properly?

Comment: Free the node after returning it? When exactly? Surely the code that it returns to will need it first.

Comment: When you say "pointer", do you mean string?

Comment: Are you trying to both free and return the same piece of data at once? You cannot use data after you have freed it, ever.

Comment: The question seems clear enough... the OP wonders how one can return an object that's allocated in his/her function, while at the same time ensuring that the object will be deallocated. Other languages use reference counting or garbage collection to manage this. I'm sure there are plenty of smart-pointer-ish solutions in C++, but for a beginner the simplest option might be to have the caller create the stack and pass it into `postEval()` as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably need to do something along the lines of this:

```
Data *data = stack->data; // or whatever type stack->data is
free(stack);
return data;
```

but I agree with the comments that the question doesn't make it clear.

Either the thing you want to free and thing thing you want to return are the same thing (in which case your plan is flawed -- there's no use returning something that's already freed, because your caller can't use it), or else they're different (in which case you need to separate them somehow, but we can't tell you exactly how because you haven't told us enough about them).

Answer (score 0):

You can just safe the data pointer and free the stackNode function.

```
stackNode
[
   Data pointer -----> [data]
]

savePointer ----> [data]
```

Free stackNode will delete everything exept data

```
return savePointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you return an auto_ptr / unique_ptr (c++11) ? Something like:

`unique_ptr<stackNode> postEval(char* equation)
{
    unique_ptr<stackNode> stack;
  .....
   return stack;
}`